# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error message?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am currently working on a project and I happen to have opened another file where code was automatically input, but I get an "invalid syntax" error on this line of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

What's wrong with this line?

The whole code of the file is this;

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import json

app = Flask("Web Translator")

@app.route("/englishToFrench")
def englishToFrench():
    textToTranslate = request.args.get('textToTranslate')
    # Write your code here
    return "Translated text to French"

@app.route("/frenchToEnglish")
def frenchToEnglish():
    textToTranslate = request.args.get('textToTranslate')
    # Write your code here
    return "Translated text to English"

@app.route("/")
def renderIndexPage():
    # Write the code to render template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

I tried looking up how to correctly input the code online, but it seems that everything seems to be right with that line of code so I don't understand why I am getting an error message.

Comment: Please, add the full error message and some more context.

Comment: Add a minimal example that I can copy/paste into a python IDE to get the same error. This is explained in “how to ask a question”.

Comment: Add a tag for the language

Comment: Because you have invalid syntax... probably on a line *before* the line you show. *You* think that line is the start of an `if` statement, but the parser apparently thinks it is an attempted continuation of a previous statement.

Comment: The error message is this; Parsing failed: 'invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 23)'pylint(syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

If the code provided is exactly what is in the file, you have no code or a `pass` below renderIndexPage().

This isn't valid syntax and would show an error below as the if is not indented.

```
def renderIndexPage():
    pass
    # Write the code to render template
```

This removes the error on the if statement.